# How to set default input when reading from the console in Java?

Tags: java

How to add any word (text) to the input stream? I want to read console input and pre-populate the line so that the user doesn't have to input the word from scratch:

```java
String ANY_WORD = "TEXT";
System.out.print("Enter: ");
// (some magic here?)
String value = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
```

What I want to see: (cursor marked by `|`):

```
Enter: TEXT|            # Default
Enter: TE|              # Press backspace twice
Enter: TEST|            # Write "ST"
```

I tried simply adding it to the prompt:

```java
System.out.print("Enter: " + ANY_WORD);
```

This *looks* like what I want, but it doesn't *work* the way I want, because I
can't edit the word:

```
Enter: TEXT|            # Default
Enter: TEXT|            # Press backspace twice, no editing
```

**UPDATE:**
If the user presses key `Enter`, the variable `value`  will be assigned the value  `TEXT` and everything that the user enters from the keyboard OR he can erase (during input) with the key `Backspace` the word `TEXT`

**UPDATE:**
so when the user was prompted to enter a sentence (using `new Scanner (System.in) .netLine()`), there was already the word "TEXT" by default. That is, as if the user had already entered it (it was possible to erase the word "TEXT")

Comment: I find this question clear enough: OP wants to read a line with a pre-populated default string, similar to Bash `read -ep "Enter name: "  -i "World"`

Comment: Do you want ANY_WORD to be default, or are you trying to put ANY_WORD always there?

Comment: @thatotherguy I think you mixed up Answer/Question in your edit :) It seem the "Answer" was answering my question in the comment.

Comment: Oof, concurrent editing

Comment: @Scratte, If the user presses key `Enter`, the variable `value`  will be assigned the value ` TEXT` and everything that the user enters from the keyboard OR he can erase (during input) with the key `Backspace` the word `TEXT`

Comment: @n199a Yes. I get it now :) Thank you. If you wish, you can remove the Question/Answer part. The rest of the text makes it very clear. I'll remove all my comments, if you wish.

Comment: @Scratte, no, let them stay. I need to `open` my question, because it is `closed`

Comment: It will go to the reopen queue (**once**) automatically when it's edited, as it has been now. No one will look at the comments for reopening. Only at the text inside the Question :) I will leave them now. Just @-ping me if you want me to remove any comments later then :)

Comment: @Scratte, thanks, i understand now :)

Comment: @Scratte, can you reopen my question now? My question is correct? :)

Comment: @n199a I cannot reopen it. No one user can do that (except diamond moderators, but they cannot be summoned :). It has to be done by several users with more than 3K reputations points, and it will take some time. I am sure that your Question is now inside a reopen queue, where users will vote to either leave it closed or to reopen it. I have bookmarked your Question, since I plan to come back and check on it.

Comment: I believe your Question is clear and that there's nothing wrong with it. As far as I am concerned your Question is fine now :)

Comment: @Scratte, thank you :)

Comment: I have the same question!!!