# System.console.readLine() default value to be able to edit

Tags: java, console-application

I am wondering if there is possible to have a default value as input when `System.console.readLine()` is triggered.
I am trying to use this feature in an interactive application.

```
Here is an example of what I desire.
String line = System.console.readLine("value=");
//A default value should be in place and editable. In the console:
>value=default

Here the "default" string should be editable
```

As per this topic, [How to set default input when reading from the console in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62562390/how-to-set-default-input-when-reading-from-the-console-in-java) is not possible. Hoping that something has been improved.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing has been improved, this is still not possible.

What I did was provided the default value in brackets and used that when empty input.

```java
String year = console.readLine("Year (2021 when empty)");
if (StringUtils.isBlank(year)) {
   year = "2021";
}
```

Comment: I was just hoping :D