# Java: On the command line, present the user with an editable option

Tags: java, command-line-interface, java.util.scanner

I have a Java CLI application (no frameworks, plain Java), in which I am getting input from the client via Scanner. I'm letting the client choose between several options (by index), and returning the resulting string. But I'd like the client to be able to edit the string before further processing. Is there a technique to request user input, but to pre-populate it with a suggestion? I'm looking for something akin to a HTML field with a value attribute.
Here's a sketch of the interaction:

```
Please choose from the list below
1 - Option 1 bla bla bla
2 - Option 2 which is entirely different
0 - None (abort)

# We read user input from scanner.nextInt()
# Assuming the user chose 1, we convert the text of Option 1 to 'option-1-bla-bla-bla'
# But we would like to give the user the option to edit that value:

Edit the value we will use:
$ option-1-bla-bla-bla # How can I present the user with the option to edit this?
```

Comment: Your rep tells me you could build something like this easily, so what's the catch :-)

Comment: @KevinHooke it is possible to be good at some technologies, but to suck at others. I have hardly any experience in CLI

Comment: And Yes, I could probably hack it using raw input and output streams, but I was hoping for something more high level

Comment: Doesn't seem easy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66225189/system-console-readline-default-value-to-be-able-to-edit

Comment: You could use JNI + Gnu Readline.

Comment: seems it isn't possible. Closing as dupe

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd I find it interesting that the majority of questions from developers learning Java are around how to capture user input from the cli using Scanner, but in reality in every day development this is rarely something we ever do, so yes, I get it :-)